# Analytic Properties of $f(x) = x^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

The function $f(x) = x^x, x > 0$ can be plotted on graphing software and inspected to see a local minimum around .367. The function is convex, decreasing from 0 to its minimum, and increasing thereafter. The derivative of the function can be found by implicit differentiation to be $f'(x) = x^x(\ln(x)+1)$.

> 1. Can the exact value of the local minimum be found?
> 2. Can someone explain intuitively why the function first decreases and then increases?
> 3. Is there anything interesting about the class of functions $\{ \, f(x) \, | \, f'(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) \, \}$

Edit: I forgot, I'll be subject to a firing squad if I don't explain what I have tried!

1. Setting the derivative equal to 0 doesn't do much for me. If this can be solved exactly without optimization algorithms, I suspect something really clever will need to happen.
2. I tried thinking about what is happing for different types of inputs (irrational $x$, rational $x$, natural $x$). Still didn't get anywhere.
3. Nothing to try really, does this class of functions come up anywhere in math?

Comment: Sure, set $f'=0$. What do you get?

Comment: As a general practice, you should identify the domain of a function you want to analyze.

Comment: As to why it first decreases and then increases, look at the sign of the derivative.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If you post an answer where you set $f' = 0$ and solve for $x$ then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @hardmath, domain added, though clearly $x > 0$ since we're in the realm of calculus and the function is discrete < 0.

Comment: @saulspatz I view the sign of the derivative as more of a witness to the fact that it increases then decreases, not a an explanation. It seems intuitive to me that if $x > y$ then $x^x > y^y$ but obviously this is not always true. What is going on in this neighborhood $x <  \approx$ .36?

Comment: I mean, I'd like you try it first. It's a fairly simple computation. If you want a hint, $x^x = e^{x\log x}$ so it is never zero.

Comment: You might be interested in the  fact that $f(x) \to 1$ as $x\to 0^+$.  So the function can be exended to be continuous on $[0,1]$ or $[0,+\infty)$, depending on your interest.  That limit at $x=0$ is related to your request to "explain intuitively".

Comment: @NinadMunshi I edited to add what I try. I hate this community so much, it's why I stopped using it. This comes up on meta all the time. This isn't a homework problem, I'm not a student, I got my masters in math 6 years ago and I'm just playing around for fun tonight now if you don't want to answer the question just go away. I studied algebraic geometry. I barely remember how to multiply numbers. I'm just intrigued by this function right now and want some answers.

Comment: @PrinceM that reaction was completely unwarranted. I like to help people learn is all, no need to bite my head off. Please take your ego somewhere else.

Comment: Let me give you some advice on how you could have handled things if you like to help people learn. You could have said something along the lines of "when setting $x^x(ln(x) + 1) = 0$, one or both of $x^x$ and $ln(x) + 1$ must be equal to zero. Can you proceed from here?". Or "remember, if $a*b = 0$ then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Can you apply this?". The "I'm not going to tell you anything until you show what you tried" is honestly just annoying.

Comment: $$f(x) = e^{g(x)} \implies f'(x) = g'(x)\times f(x).$$  Although I am fairly inexperienced in differential equations, consider the equation $$y' = y \times g(x).$$  Here, $y$ is normally used as a shorthand for *some* unknown function in $x, f(x).$

Comment: @PrinceM while that's fine for someone seeing the topic for the first time that level of hand holding can be seen as patronizing for someone who has done that before. Darned if you do, darned if you don't as they say. How about taking personal responsibility for your reaction as opposed trying to pin blame on the other party? I am not responsible for you feel about the community, and a little communication from you ahead of time on your circumstances would have made it easier to understand what you wanted.

Comment: @PrinceM There is no question that there is a general conflict on mathSE between what mathSE reviewers want to see in a query versus the information that query posters want to provide.  For a consideration of how to favorably impress mathSE reviewers, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good habit to rewrite $a^b$ as $\exp(b\ln(a))$. In our case this is $f(x)=x^x = \exp(x\ln(x))$, which is easier to study. The expression makes sense for $x>0$, doesn't make sense for $x<0$, and leaves some room for debate at $x=0$ although it's sensible to take $0^0=1$. The function is then continuous on $\{x\colon x \ge 0\}$.

The derivative, like you said, is $f'(x)=x^x(1+\ln(x))$. For this to be $0$, either $x^x$ should be $0$ (never happens, as $\exp$ never vanishes) or $1+\ln(x)=0$ which means $\ln(x)=-1$ or $x = \frac{1}{e}$. If there is a minimum – and indeed there is – it must be there. You can verify this in any number of ways, such as taking a second derivative or just checking nearby values.

The function decreases when $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{e}$ and increases afterwards.

I can't imagine why you wanted to understand the behavior for rational and irrational values of the argument.

Exponential functions arise all over the place in mathematics. This particular function isn't super common, but it pops up here and there.

Comment: What does exp mean and why do we use it

Comment: @SomeGuy $\exp(x)$ means the same thing as $e^x$, it's just used for better readability at times than a tiny exponent filled with text.

Comment: Thanks! In all honesty I should have been able to solve for the minimum (zoinks!). I think the function does make sense for some $x < 0$ if im not mistaken, for example at $x = -n$. I still have trouble grasping why the function would decrease before $\frac{1}{e}$, but I also understand "why" questions in math are hard to answer because it is more of a psychological thing. Maybe looking at taylor expansions would satisfy me. Also, just to be clear, the third part of my question was asking if there is a branch of domain where functions whose derivatives are the product of the  original function

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks!!!!!!!!! so much !!!!!!!!!

Comment: with another function are ever useful or studied.

Comment: @PrinceM if you were to take continuity for granted and you knew $x^x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ ahead of time, then you could use the fact that $a^b < 1$ for $a\in(0,1)$ and $b>0$ to assert that the function has to decrease from that point. Another way of looking at it is mean value theorem since "$0^0$" $=1^1=1$.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum is attained at $x=\frac1e$ as can be seen by setting the derivative equal to $0$ and solving for $x$.

Your statement in a comment that it is not always true that if $x>y>0$ then $x^x>y^x$ is false.  We have $$x>y\implies \log x > \log x\implies x\log x > x\log y \implies x^x>y^x  $$

Perhaps you meant to say it is not always true that $x>y>0$ implies $x^x>y^y$.  This is true.  Taking logarithms, there's no particular reason to believe that $x\log x > y\log y$ and indeed, it isn't always true.

To try to explain it intuitively, note first that we're concerned with numbers $0<x<y<1$.  When you raise such a number to a power, the larger the power, the smaller the result.  When we compare $x^x$ and $y^y$, for some choices of $x$ and $y$, this effect dominates, and $y^y$ is the smaller of the two numbers.  For other choices of $x$ and $y$, the fact that $x$ is smaller dominates.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo, I think I edited it right after, you must have caught it before I changed it :)

Comment: And thank you for the intuitive explanation!

Answer (score 2):

For your other question, we can rewrite the equation as an ODE

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = g(x)\cdot y$$

which we can separate variables and integrate to solve. The final answer is always of the form

$$y = C\exp\left(G(x)\right)$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant and $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$.

Comment: This is interesting! Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @PrinceM sure! Anything of this form always shows up as exponential, and shows up frequently when you're doing things like drawing a phase portrait and solving for a streamline, or anything involving a complicated time evolution of some system (even quantum mechanical) since the equation is stating "where you want to go is dependent on where you are right now"

Comment: I like that interpretation of the result.

Answer (score 2):

for question 3:
$f'(x) = f(x) g(x) \implies \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = g(x) \implies ln|f(x)| = \int g(x) = G(x) \implies f(x) = e^{G(x)}$

there are 2 cases... if $G(x) = ln(h(x))$, then $f(x) = h(x)$ otherwise it is an exponent. Either ways $f(x)>0$ is the only property I can see... Can we say that means f(x) is exponential?

Answer (score 2):

Among the properties of the function $x^x$, don't forget

- The antiderivative $\quad \text{Sphd}(x)=\int_0^x t^{\,t}\, dt\quad$ namely the Sophomore's dream function (Note below).
- The inverse function of $\quad x^x=y(x)\quad$ which is
  $$x(y)=e^{W\big(\ln(y)\big)}$$

$W$ is the Lambert W function (graph below)

[image]

The graph is a copy of page 13 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function .

Note : In this paper one can find many properties of the antiderivative of $x^x$ wich is a special function (not standardized).